# 線形補間をLerpと呼ぶのはなぜ

Tags: 数学, 専門用語, 英語

線形補間をLerpと呼ぶのはなぜでしょうか

[Linear Interpolate の略](https://ejje.weblio.jp/content/%E3%80%8A%E3%82%B3%E3%83%B3%E3%83%94%E3%83%A5%E3%83%BC%E3%82%BF%E3%80%8BLinear+Interpolate+%E3%81%AE%E7%95%A5)だという説を個人ブログなどでも複数見たのですが、どう略したらそうなるのか分かりません
**L**in**e**a**r** Inter**p**olate から **L**inear Int**erp**olate まで複数考えられますがどれもしっくりきません。

どういう由来なのでしょうか。

マルチポスト: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/549250

Answer (score 8):

1. [Jargon File](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%B8%E3%83%A3%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B4%E3%83%B3%E3%83%95%E3%82%A1%E3%82%A4%E3%83%AB)に意味用法が[載っている](http://catb.org/jargon/html/L/LERP.html)
2. leap(跳ぶ)という一般語の発音に寄せ、「跳ぶ」ことと「二地点間を跳躍して埋める」ことの意味が似ていてイメージがしやすい

という単純な経緯から人口に膾炙して定着したのではないかと推測しています。
※特に後者は完全に私個人の空想です。

[en.wikipedia.org](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_interpolation#History_and_applications)では "In that field's jargon it is sometimes called a lerp." と書かれています。
上記および[en.wiktionary.org](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/lerp#Etymology_2)にも由来は書かれておらず、誰がどうしてこの略語を当てたのかは分かりませんでした。

[リンク先](https://pippin.gimp.org/image-processing/chap_resampling.html)を"lerp"で検索するとソースのコメントに2003年時点のJargon Fileが引用されています。

> -- LERP
> -- /lerp/, vi.,n.
> --
> -- Quasi-acronym for Linear Interpolation, used as a verb or noun for
> -- the operation. "Bresenham's algorithm lerps incrementally between the
> -- two endpoints of the line." (From Jargon File (4.4.4, 14 Aug 2003)

結局「少なくとも今世紀に入ってからLinear Interpolateの略語として一定の理解を獲得していますが、初出や正確な由来は見つかりませんでした」という、しまらない回答になってしまいました。
私の検索力ではこれが限界でしたが、Google検索上位ではこの程度の内容しかヒットしないように感じています。